# How do I get my scene view back to 0 or whatever it is by default?

Tags: unity, 2d, camera

All my tiles/sprites have 0 as their position on the Z axis, except my main cam which has -10.

For some reason I suddenly couldn't zoom in without everything disappearing, I switched to 3D view to see where I was and it seemed like I was miles away from my tiles on the z axis. I placed a sprite into my level to check and it placed itself at -57,000 on the z axis.

How do I get my scene view back to 0 or whatever it is by default?

Answer (score 1):

Select an object you want to center your view on and press the <kbd>F</kbd> key to snap your scene view camera to that object, zoomed to fit it in view. "Frame Selected" is the name of this shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

In the top right (I believe that is the default), there is a section called transformation. You can change those numbers to all 0. I believe there is also an option to 'reset' as well in the transform section.